# Autocalculate inside of an excel cell visual basic

Tags: vba, excel

On a single worksheet in Excel I would like to have different ranges calculate themselves after I input a number.

For example, In range A1:C4 I want to multiply by 4

so that if I enter 1 in cell A1 I get 4, 2 I get 8 etc.

Then in range B12:F14 I want to multiply by 2
so that if I enter 1 in cell B12 I get 2, 2 I get 4 etc.

Currently I have the following VB that works for an entire sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = Target.Value / 100
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You just need to set up some conditionals to see what `Range` the `Target` is in.  I will show you an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add some logic to check and see what `Range` contains the `Target`.  You can do this pretty simply with some `If...Then` statements.

First, I assign two range variables `rng1` and `rng2` which represent the ranges you mention (`A1:C4` and `B12:F14` respectively), then, I check to see if the `Target` is in one of those ranges, using the `Intersect` function.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng1 = Range("A1:C4")
    Set rng2 = Range("B12:F14")
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
        '## Determine what to do with the cell, based on what range it's in
        If Not Intersect(Target, rng1) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Value = Target.Value * 4
        End If
        If Not Intersect(Target, rng2) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Value = Target.Value * 2
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This way, you have two different operations that might happen, depending on where the `Target` is. If the `Target` is not in either of these ranges, then nothing will happen to it.

You can add additional `Range` variables and `If...Then` statements to account for other calculations you might need.